# Charging a 200 Ah battery with 2 A current

Tags: battery-charging

If I charge 200 Ah battery bank of 6 batteries with 2-3 A current, will it cause damage to the battery? I have a setting in my UPS which can lower the charging current. The question I have is if I set it to lower current (presently set at 12 A), will it damage the battery?

Comment: You should think about the time needed for a full charge. I assume a perfect battery without loss. 100 % charge of 200 Ah with 2 A current will take 100 hours or about 4 days. With 12 A 16.67 hours will be needed. The battery should be full charged before the next power outage. You want to be prepared for the next outage soon.

Comment: I have a separate 15A charger I can turn on demand. The problem is the UPS is drawing too much current and interfering with the diesel generator on the facility. The changeover switch limit is 3A. So anything over that is flipping my UPS on and off continuously

Comment: What kind of batteries are in your UPS?

Comment: 200AH lead acid SMF

Comment: 12A @ a charge voltage of 14.5V is 174W. 174W from a 120V supply (your diesel generator) is only 1.45A. Throwing some inefficiency into the calculation and call it 2A. Does that 2A *really* interfere with a big diesel generator? I'm skeptical ... Looks like an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: If the generator isn't outputting a perfect sine wave (most don't), then the UPS will be unhappy with it and cause the UPS to activate.  UPSes watch for voltage distortions with the assumption that they are an indication that power is going away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no.

Excessive heat, which may be seen when charging with very high currents (or step changes such as 0.01C to 0.3C to 0.01C, periodically), damages the battery. Charging with lower currents doesn't generate an excessive heat but there are few things you should keep in mind:

- Self discharging rate
- Max allowed floating charge voltage

The last item is important because you shouldn't allow the battery voltage to exceed the floating charging voltage for a long time. It may damage or even destroy the battery. If your charger is able to limit the current as well as the voltage then it's fine.

If everything is okay then the problem reduces to the time: It'll take longer, so might be impractical for your needs e.g. if your application is something like charging the battery during the day and leaving it discharging during the night, then it may not be possible to get it ready for the next night.

Answer (score 1):

> *The question I have is if I set it to lower current (presently set at
> 12A), will it damage the battery ?*

- What if you set to the charge current to zero amps? Would that damage your battery?
- Wouldn't disconnecting the battery be exactly the same as charging it at zero amps?

It's called a [trickle charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trickle_charging) by the way

If in doubt, read the battery data sheet or, contact the battery supplier or equipment supplier.

Comment: I have deleted my earlier ones but, I believe you are still missing my point.